# How to properly crossfade text on hover with jquery

Tags: jquery, hover, mouseover

http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/8wf5E/ (works now - using .hover() )

The following obviously fails when hovering over the fading divs since that triggers the mouseout and in. I only need the actual text to fade in and out, the wrapping divs are only for containment and debugging. A solution without position:absolute is preferred

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="one" class="fade">One</div>
  <div id="two" class="fade">Two</div>
</div>   

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#container").mouseover(function () {
    $("#one").fadeOut("slow");
    $("#two").fadeIn("slow");
  }).mouseout(function () {
    $("#two").fadeOut("slow");
    $("#one").fadeIn("slow");
  });;
}); 

div { margin:3px; width:80px; height:80px; float:left; }
div#container { width: 100px; height:100px; border:1px solid black}
div#one { position:absolute; border:1px solid red;}
div#two { position:absolute; border:1px solid green; display:none; }
```

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3670487/jquery-text-fade-transition-from-one-text-to-another

Comment: @Joshua - not quite. The first solution fades in AFTER the fadeout, the next solution crossfades nicely but not on hover, just using interval

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend using the [`hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) function for this kind of functionality...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#container").hover(
    function(e) { 
      $("#one").fadeOut("slow");
      $("#two").fadeIn("slow");
    },
    function(e) {
      $("#two").fadeOut("slow");
      $("#one").fadeIn("slow");      
    }
  );
});
```

It [fixes](http://jsfiddle.net/8wf5E/21/) this particular problem.

Comment: Okee, that is what I looked at and dismissed. But it is the better solution

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for this jQuery code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#container").mouseenter(function () {
    $("#one").fadeOut("slow");
    $("#two").fadeIn("slow");
  }).mouseleave(function () {
    $("#two").fadeOut("slow");
    $("#one").fadeIn("slow");
  });;
});
```

EDIT : You can also do it using a bit of CSS3 magic ;)

```
div { margin:3px; width:80px; height:80px; float:left; }
div#container { width: 100px; height:100px; border:1px solid black}
div#one { position:absolute; border:1px solid red;-webkit-transition:opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;}
div#two { position:absolute; border:1px solid green; opacity:0;-webkit-transition:opacity 0.5s ease-in-out; }

div#container:hover #two{
 opacity:1;}
div#container:hover #one{
 opacity:0;}
```

=> http://jsfiddle.net/3WZKx/1/

Comment: I don't see how ! You could do without the position:absolute on the CSS but you'd need to set it with jQuery and I'm pretty sure you should not do that ;) => http://jsfiddle.net/3WZKx/2/

Comment: The CSS is not fading (I think it could in HTML5) but thanks for the tip. I change my accept because the .hover feels correct.

Comment: Ah - no I did not mean without DECLARING the absolute, I mean fade some text in a div where the text was just being replaced without positioning

Answer (score 3):

Using `mouseleave()` instead of `mouseout()` seems to be better.
See [here](http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/).

Comment: See @Jibou's suggestion. Works. Thanks