# CSS text fade in vertically

Tags: css, css-transitions

I'm trying to make text fade in vertically, I thought of changing the line-height over time but didn't really know how to do so, any help ?

The div code:

```
#bigimage {
width: 270px;
height: 200px;
float: left;
text-align: center;
line-height: 200px;
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
color: #FFF;
font-size: 36px;
transition: all ease-in-out 0.2s;
cursor: pointer;
animation: fadein 2s;
-moz-animation: fadein 2s;
-webkit-animation: fadein 2s;
-o-animation: fadein 2s;    
}
```

Comment: When do you say _fade_, do you mean moving, appearing,...?

Comment: sorry for being unclear, I mean by making the text move from lets say line-height 270px to line-height 200px when appearing.

Comment: I guess that you only do that with action: I mean, with an `:hover`, `:active`, `:focus`,... It's easy to use. Check [this](http://www.impressivewebs.com/css3-transitions-without-hover/). Or [this](http://thecreativeservicesblog.com/2011/10/css3-animations-using-transition-tranform-and-keyframes/)

Comment: Those are pseudo-classes for hovering, clicking or focusing an element. What I want to do is when I load the page, the text fades in vertically, at the moment it just fades in.

Comment: Please check if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3670487/jquery-text-fade-transition-from-one-text-to-another) might help you. :) I am not sure if you can do that only with _CSS_, you need put some _JS_ into it...

Comment: Haven't worked it out yet. Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add the keyframes moving from the first property to the last. Add this to your stylesheet

```
@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    0% {line-height: 280px;}
  100% {line-height: 200px;}
}

@-moz-keyframes fadein {
    0% {line-height: 280px;}
  100% {line-height: 200px;}
}
@-o-keyframes fadein {
    0% {line-height: 280px;}
  100% {line-height: 200px;}
}
@keyframes fadein {
    0% {line-height: 280px;}
  100% {line-height: 200px;}
}
```

Since I am seting as last property the css property of the element, there isn't any need to set a fillmode.

### [updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/78KUH/)