# Having Issue on Adding fadeIn() to .html()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please let me know why I am not able to add `.fadeIn()` animation into `.html()` in following code?

```js
jQuery(function() {
  var i = 0;
  var text = ["Welcome", "Hi", "Sup dude"];

  setInterval(function() {
    $("#changeText").fadeIn(300).html(text[i]);
    i++;
    if (i >= text.length) {
      i = 0;
    }
  }, 2500)

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="changeText">This is For Test</div>
```

Comment: You're never fading it out, so there's nothing to fade in.

Comment: `$("#changeText").hide().html(text[i]).fadeIn(300);` ?

Comment: @Barmar, thanks actually I already tried adding the fadeOutt() at the end of  statement but it didn't do anything

Comment: @charlietfl, thanks I am going to check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to hide the text before you fade it in.
You can also try to fadeOut the text to make the affect better.

```js
jQuery(function() {
  var i = 0;
  var text = ["Welcome", "Hi", "Sup dude"];

  setInterval(function() {
    $("#changeText").hide().html(text[i]).fadeIn(300);
    i++;
    if (i >= text.length) {
      i = 0;
    }
  }, 2500)

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="changeText">This is For Test</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have indicated, you have to hide the element to fade it in.  You can simply hide it, or use the method shown here which is a slightly nicer trannsition: [jQuery text fade/transition from one text to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3670487/jquery-text-fade-transition-from-one-text-to-another)

To show it in your code, something like this:

```
jQuery(function() {
    var changeInt = 0;
    var i = 0;
    var text = ["Welcome", "Hi", "Sup dude"];

    setInterval(function() {
        $("#changeText").fadeOut(function() {
            $(this).text(text[i])
        }).fadeIn();
        i++;
        if (i >= text.length) {
            i = 0;
        }
    }, 2500)
})
```