# Animate (or fadeIn) a .text change

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I am close to finishing a project but there is only one thing that I can't get to work, and that is how to animate this function:

```
    $('.box').click(function(){
var description = $(this).find('.hide').text();

$('.description').text(description);
});
```

So what you see here is that I get a text from an element and place it into another element. But it is really rough it's just 'pop' and there it's. I tried serval things like putting .fadeIn() into the chain. Also I was thinking about doing it inside .animate() but I couldn't find a way to put it in. So my question is: Is there a way to animate this? or is it just simply not possible?

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: Would `$('.description').hide().text(description).fadeIn();` do what you want?

Comment: Yes, I missed the point xD. I wanted to keep the code simple so I typed a new peace of code but does exactly the same (the code normaly works, my point of focus is the animation)

Comment: Does this help?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3670487/jquery-text-fade-transition-from-one-text-to-another

Comment: Ow let me take a look

Comment: Well problem solved @OliverRadini

Comment: Glad to hear it, for some reason I can't add it as an answer to resolve the question, but never mind!