# How to animate change in text value using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

### What is happening

[image]

### What I want

Instead of having an abrupt transition, I want the numbers to `fadeIn` for `300ms`. So when I click on a number, it fades into view on the `#Demo-Card`, and if I click another number, then it fades into view. I've been trying to use `animate()` but to no avail.

If anyone could help me with this, it would be greatly appreciated!

### My Code

*HTML*

```
<div id="Demo-Pane" class="container">
                <div id="Demo-Card">
                    <div class="problem-header">
                        <h3><span class="problem-number">11</span> <span class="problem-equation">Problem</span></h3>
                    </div>
                     ...
                </div>
            </div>
```

*jQuery*

```
$(document).ready(function () {
...
    $(".nav-pills").children("li").click(function(){
        ...
        /*Change problem number on #Demo-Card*/
        newProblemNumber = $(this).children("a").text();
        $("#Demo-Card").children(".problem-header").find(".problem-number").text(newProblemNumber);
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/14ongm/apjgqahm/)

### Note

My question is not a duplicate because unlike that question, I only want to change the value of the text and then fade that in. In addition I do not want to use `fadeIn` or `fadeOut`, as @DaniP said, because I don't want to move the Problem text.

Comment: have you tried delay()? see the reference http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_delay.asp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery text fade/transition from one text to another?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3670487/jquery-text-fade-transition-from-one-text-to-another)

Comment: why not use fadeIn() / fadeOut() ?

Comment: @singebatteur maybe because fadein - out will make the element display-none causing the "Problem" word go to left and after abrupt go to right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `callback function()` for animate this way:

> Set opacity to `0` -- When finish change the text and animate again to `1`

```
$("#Demo-Card").children(".problem-header").find(".problem-number").animate(
    {opacity:0},200,function(){
       $(this).text(newProblemNumber).animate({'opacity':1})
    });
});
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/apjgqahm/6/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.fadeout()` then `.fadein()`

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
     $("button").click(function(){
        newProblemNumber =23;
        $("#Demo-Card").children(".problem-header")
        .find(".problem-number")
        .text(newProblemNumber)
        .fadeOut(150).fadeIn(150);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Demo-Pane" class="container">
                <div id="Demo-Card">
                    <div class="problem-header">
                        <h3><span class="problem-number">11</span> <span class="problem-equation">Problem</span></h3>
                    </div>
                   
                </div>
            </div>

<button>click here</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#Demo-Card").children(".problem-header").find(".problem-number").hide().html(newProblemNumber).show('slow');
```

Hope it helps!