# creating jquery fadein and fadeout to replace html text

Tags: javascript, jquery

Just wanted to ask a quick question with my jquery code. just started using Jquery/JS and I feel like there is a cleaner way to do this. It does fade to "and much more" but when it goes back, its not a fade its more of a switch.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  setInterval(swapText, 4000);

  function swapText(){
    $("#profile-text-fade").fadeOut(500, function() {
      $(this).fadeIn(1000).delay(2000);
      $(this).html('and much more!');
      $(this).fadeIn(2000, function () {
        $(this).html('In the making, Soon to show all the work I can crate!');
      });
    });
  }
});
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #FFC85E;
}
.aligh {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.jumbotron_resize {
  padding-top: 18%;
  padding-bottom: 10em;
  margin-bottom: 10em;
  background-color: #FFC85E;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

h1, p{
text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="description" content="Profile Test Page">
    <meta name="keywords" content="HTML,CSS,XML,JavaScript">
    <meta name="author" content="Salvador Cervantes">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel='stylesheet' type:'text/css' href='../CSS/main.css'>
    <title>
       Test page
    </title>
  </head>


  <body>
    <div class="align">
      <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid jumbotron_resize">
        <div class="container">
          <h1 class="display-3">test Profile</h1>
          <p  id='profile-text-fade' class="lead">In the making, Soon to show all the work I can crate!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <footer>
        <div>
          <p>&copy 2017
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src='../js/main.js'></script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Now what I'm trying to do is to fadeout the text that is on the webpage and replace it with "and much more!" and then fade back to the original text of "in the making...".  right now, the last part just snaps back to place and dones't fade. Any help would be amazing!

Thank you

Comment: Please post all the relevant code, including the HTML and CSS in your question.

Comment: your code is working fine:-  https://jsfiddle.net/fo1yyono/

Comment: Sorry I have edited my response question of making the transaction back to the original text as a fade, Right now it's just snapping back and not fading

Comment: Possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17004791/7741359

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your text is not fading in as you don't fade it out.  ie it does: `$("#div").fadeIn().fadeIn()`

Change your last fadeIn to:

```
$(this).fadeOut(500, function() { 
    $(this).fadeIn(2000, function () {
        $(this).html('In the making, Soon to show all the work I can crate!');
```

---

You might like to consider a refactor to create a list of messages and then simply loop through them.  This will also be re-usable and allow you to add more messages without lots of nasty callback-chaining, eg:

```js
var msgs = ["msg1", "msg2"];
var indx = 0;
$("#div").text(msgs[indx]);
setInterval(function() {
  $("#div").fadeOut(
    500, 
    function() { 
      indx++;
      if (indx>=msgs.length) indx=0;
      $(this).text(msgs[indx]); 
      $(this).fadeIn(500);
    });
}, 3000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='div'>initial message</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I actually tried to first part and it was just acting strange, so i used the example you gave me and modified it a little and BAM! it works! thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you needed edited your code, you have to fadeOut it before the last fadeIn, (i have slightly increased the interval for some smooth effect)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  swapText();
  setInterval(swapText, 6000);

  function swapText(){
  $("#profile-text-fade").stop();
    $("#profile-text-fade").fadeOut(1500, function() {
      $(this).html('and much more!');
      $(this).fadeIn(1500);
      
      $(this).fadeOut(1500, function () {
       $(this).fadeIn(1500);
       $(this).html('In the making, Soon to show all the work I can crate!');
      });
    });
  }
});
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #FFC85E;
}
.aligh {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.jumbotron_resize {
  padding-top: 18%;
  padding-bottom: 10em;
  margin-bottom: 10em;
  background-color: #FFC85E;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

h1, p{
text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="description" content="Profile Test Page">
    <meta name="keywords" content="HTML,CSS,XML,JavaScript">
    <meta name="author" content="Salvador Cervantes">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel='stylesheet' type:'text/css' href='../CSS/main.css'>
    <title>
       Test page
    </title>
  </head>


  <body>
    <div class="align">
      <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid jumbotron_resize">
        <div class="container">
          <h1 class="display-3">test Profile</h1>
          <p  id='profile-text-fade' class="lead">In the making, Soon to show all the work I can crate!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <footer>
        <div>
          <p>&copy 2017
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src='../js/main.js'></script>
  </body>
  </html>
```