# Fade div without .fadeIn() and .fadeOut()

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to show an alert in my page for a while and then hide it.

I need to do that without using `.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut()` because it changes CSS display property and mess up with my alert.

So, I found this ([jQuery text fade/transition from one text to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3670487/jquery-text-fade-transition-from-one-text-to-another)):

```
$('#container').animate({'opacity': 1}, 1000, function () {
    $(this).text('new text');
}).animate({'opacity': 0}, 1000);
```

And it's working.

The problem is that it shows and hides too quickly and I need to **keep the message for a while in the screen** before it disappears. Is there a way to add a delay in it?

How can I do that?

Comment: "keep for a while before it disappears".  I'm confused by that statment, looking at this logic, it hides the container, and then shows it again.  It's not the inverse.  ?

Comment: I don't seem to understand what the problem is. Isn't that code you posted already a fade effect? Are you trying to hide the container but not the text?

Comment: @Taplar No. My container is already hidden and the code above, at least here, shows the container and hides it.

Comment: Opacity of 0 is hidden, which is the first thing you do, before you change the text and the second animation of opacity 1 (to show it again) happens.  https://jsfiddle.net/pufeLa5n/

Comment: @MauricioCárdenas the problem is that it shows my div and already hides it and I need to keep the message in the screen for a while before it disappears.

Comment: So you want to keep text1 for a while before it changes to text2, instead of just dissapearing and then fading in text2, right?

Comment: @MauricioCárdenas I just need to show my alert for a while and then hide it.

Comment: @Taplar My alert div is hidden. I need to show it with my message and then hide the div again. That's it. Question updated.

Comment: So, *again*, why are you setting the opacity to 0 first and not 1 first, which would cause it to **show** first, not hide first?

Comment: Please try both code snippets I left below, then tell me if any of those work for you, or if they're doing something that works for you, so I can move on from there.

Comment: @Taplar Ok. Just fixed it here. So now, how can I keep the message in the screen for a while before fade it out?

Comment: Just make the animation longer I guess, change those "1000" for higher values so it stays in screen for longer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you can take it in steps.

- If it starts out hidden, you can go ahead and change the text.
- After you change it, animate the opacity to fade it in
- After that is done, delay the next animation for however long you want it to be visible.
- After the delay, hide it again

```js
$('#container')
  .text('My error Text')
  .animate({ opacity: 1 }, 1000)
  .delay(3000)
  .animate({ opacity: 0}, 1000);
```

```css
#container {
  opacity: 0;
  border-color: rgb(64, 32, 32);
  background-color: rgb(128, 32, 32);
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for explanation and working example. Working perfect here.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#container').animate({'opacity': 0.5}, 1000).animate({'opacity': 1}, 1000, function () {
    $(this).text('new text');
});
```

This will make the animation take 1 second to go from hidden to half opacity, then it will execute a second animation, in which you will be changing the text and then going from 0.5 to full opacity. Let me know if it works and does what you need.

If you're trying to hide your alert AFTER you showed it for a couple seconds, do this:

```
$('#container').animate({'opacity': 1}, 1000, function () {
   $(this).text('new text');
}).animate({'opacity': 0}, 1000);
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and help!

Answer (score 1):

the animate function takes the "duration" as a parameter, so the `1000` in the code means 1 thousand milliseconds= 1 second

Just use a smaller value in the opacity 1, to show it inmmediately, and a larger one en the opacity:0

like:

```
    $('#container').animate({'opacity': 1}, 100, function () {
    $(this).text('new text');
}).animate({'opacity': 0}, 7000);
```

this will show the text in 100 millisenconds and fade it in 7 seconds.

Comment: Thank you for your help!