# How do I write a nice, soft modifier script or improve this jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have an example, but how can I apply the effect? like fade-in. this is my example

````
<script>          
jQuery(function ($) {
    var roles = ['الرجاء اختيار لغتك', 'Choisissez votre langue', '请选择您的语言', 'Please select your language', 'Выберите ваш язык', 'Selecione seu idioma', 'لطفا زبان خود را انتخاب کنید', 'Please select your language', 'Lütfen dilinizi seçiniz', '言語を選択してください', 'შეარჩიე შენი ენა', 'Please select your language', 'בחר את השפה שלך', 'Sila Pilih Bahasa Anda', '請選擇您的語言', 'Please Select Your Language', 'Виберіть свою мову', '언어를 선택하십시오', 'अपनी भाषा का चयन करें'];
    //used to determine which is the next roles to be displayed
    var counter = 0;
    var $role = $('.role-cha-l')
    //repeat the passed function at the specified interval - it is in milliseconds
    setInterval(function () {
        //display the role and increment the counter to point to next role
        $role.text(roles[counter++]);
        //if it is the last role in the array point back to the first item
        if (counter >= roles.length) {
            counter = 11;
        }
    }, 2500)
})  </script>```
````

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about how to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It will make things easier for those trying to help you and increase your chances of quickly getting a solution to your problem.

Comment: Please do read [the documentation for `fadeIn()`](https://api.jquery.com/fadein/) and other [effects](https://api.jquery.com/category/effects/) in jQuery's documentation. Attempt to apply the functions as the examples show, and if you have problems, ask a specific question.

Comment: I think this answer would give you a nice push in the right direction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3670487/jquery-text-fade-transition-from-one-text-to-another

Comment: Thank you very much friends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would do the trick:

```js
    var roles = ['الرجاء اختيار لغتك', 'Choisissez votre langue', '请选择您的语言', 'Please select your language', 'Выберите ваш язык', 'Selecione seu idioma', 'لطفا زبان خود را انتخاب کنید', 'Please select your language', 'Lütfen dilinizi seçiniz', '言語を選択してください', 'შეარჩიე შენი ენა', 'Please select your language', 'בחר את השפה שלך', 'Sila Pilih Bahasa Anda', '請選擇您的語言', 'Please Select Your Language', 'Виберіть свою мову', '언어를 선택하십시오', 'अपनी भाषा का चयन करें'];
    //used to determine which is the next roles to be displayed
    var counter = 0;
    var $role = $('#role-cha-l')
    //repeat the passed function at the specified interval - it is in milliseconds
    setInterval(function () {
        //display the role and increment the counter to point to next role
      
        $role.fadeOut(1000,function(){$(this).text(roles[counter++]).fadeIn(1000);
});


        //if it is the last role in the array point back to the first item
        if (counter >= roles.length) {
            counter = 11;
        }
    }, 2000)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="role-cha-l">
Kies uw taal
</div>
```

Comment: Heel erg bedankt